# Opening onscreen keyboard wxpython

Tags: windows, input, wxpython, tablet, on-screen-keyboard

I'm developing an app using wxpython for use specifically with a Microsoft surface, which requires text input. Is there a way to automatically bring up the onscreen keyboard when an input box is selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an onscreen keyboard with wxPython for your applications. If you want keyboard to appear when you click your app's wx.TextCtrl, you just need to bind wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN and/or wx.EVT_LEFT_UP events to it. However, if you want keyboard to appear when any app's input is clicked then it is really hard to achieve, instead you can assign a function key to popup.